# Responsiveness not working on mobile device, but is when browser on computer is resized

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, mobile, responsive-design, media-queries

Okay, first of all, yes, I do have `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` set in my head.

When I view the site on my mobile device, it is respecting the initial scale=1 and is not just resizing the default layout, but it seems to be ignoring media queries (which I've never come across before). When I resize my browser it does work though.

For instance I have this in my css:

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {

  .container {
    width: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding: 0 20px;
  }
}
```

When I resize my browser below 767px, everything nested in the container class respects the padding. When I view on my phone, nothing does, as if it was still pulling from the default setting where that class has a padding of 0.

Has anyone come across this before? I appreciate any advice you can offer.

BTW. Website is circlephotography.ca

with thanks,

Comment: Looks like its working fine on iphone. Look at the screenshots http://imgur.com/AwbVoHv,2dIv8yx

Comment: Thanks for that Gokhan, helps narrow it down. Must be an issue with my phone, not the code.

Comment: Check your sites responsiveness in here http://responsivetest.net/#u=http://www.circlephotography.ca/  You can find the resolution that causes the problem and fix your css